# Package git not found during installation in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, apt

I used this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Here is the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bubuntu%5D+Package+git+is+not+available